# Big data visualization for multiple sampled data points from a large log

Tags: python, pandas, plot, statistics, scikit-learn

I have a log file which I need to plot in python with different data points as a multi line plot with a line for each unique point , the problem is that in some samples some points would be missing and new points would be added in another, as shown is an example with each line denoting a sample of n points where n is variable:

2015-06-20 16:42:48,135  current stats=[ ('keypassed', 13), ('toy', 2), ('ball', 2),('mouse', 1) ...]
2015-06-21 16:42:48,135  current stats=[ ('keypassed', 20, ('toy', 5), ('ball', 7), ('cod', 1), ('fish', 1) ... ]

in the above 1 st sample 'mouse '  is present but absent in the second line with new data points in each sample added like 'cod','fish'

so how can this be done in python in the quickest and cleanest way? are there any existing python utilities which can help to plot this timed log file? Also being a log file the samples are thousands in numbers so the visualization should be able to properly display it.

Interested to apply multivariate [hexagonal binning](http://meccanismocomplesso.org/en/hexagonal-binning) to this and different color hexagoan for each unique column "ball,mouse ... etc". scikit offers hexagoanal binning but cant figure out how to render different colors for each hexagon based on the unique data point. Any other visualization technique would also help in this.

Comment: I believe you could use pandas and it's integration with matplotlib to accomplish this.

Comment: This is really 2 questions:  how to import to pandas, and then how to plot (and the answer to the second depends on the first).  I would suggest getting it into pandas first and showing that, then someone can likely give you good suggestions on plotting it.  Although, getting it into pandas may be the harder part...

Comment: @JohnE one of the answer has already done the pandas part and simple potting , i need hexagonal binning

Answer (score 1):

Getting the data into pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['timestamp','name','value'])
with open(logfilepath) as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      timestamp = line.split(',')[0]
      #the data part of each line can be evaluated directly as a Python list
      data = eval(line.split('=')[1])
      #convert the input data from wide format to long format
      for name, value in data:
         df = df.append({'timestamp':timestamp, 'name':name, 'value':value}, 
                             ignore_index = True)

#convert from long format back to wide format, and fill null values with 0
df2 = df.pivot_table(index = 'timestamp', columns = 'name')
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
df2
Out[142]: 
                    value                             
name                 ball cod fish keypassed mouse toy
timestamp                                             
2015-06-20 16:42:48     2   0    0        13     1   2
2015-06-21 16:42:48     7   1    1        20     0   5
```

Plot the data:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
df2.value.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the plot is a mess due to thousands of entries how to make it better visualized then a simple line plot?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you just want to see the most common 10 terms maybe?  or the least common ?

Comment: no i want to see how terms evolve over time so i need to display all the terms

Comment: do you have a link to an example of the kind of thing youre after? i can't think of how you would do it off the top of my head

Comment: interested to apply hexagonal binning to this http://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/hexagonal-binning/

Comment: to be more specific Multivariate Hexagonal Binning with different color for each of toy, ball etc